# Convert unicode codepoint to UTF8 hex in python

Tags: python, unicode

I want to convert a number of unicode codepoints read from a file to their UTF8 encoding.

e.g I want to convert the string `'FD9B'` to the string `'EFB69B'`.

I can do this manually using string literals like this:

```
u'\uFD9B'.encode('utf-8')
```

but I cannot work out how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) to convert the number to character, then encode that:

```
>>> chr(int('fd9b', 16)).encode('utf-8')
'\xef\xb6\x9b'
```

This is the string itself. If you want the string as ASCII hex, you'd need to walk through and convert each character `c` to hex, using `hex(ord(c))` or similar.

***Note***: If you are still stuck with Python 2, you can use [`unichr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) instead.

Comment: The output is not as specified by the question. Anyway, if the OP is happy…

Comment: FYI for Py3K it's `chr(int('fd9b', 16)).encode('utf-8')`.

Comment: @tzot: `''.join('{:02X}'.format(n) for n in chr(int('FD9B', 16)).encode())` gives the string `'EFB69B'` in Python 3.

Comment: I edited your answer to go with the Python 3 solution and adding a note in case someone is still stuck with Python 2. I hope you don't mind... `chr(int('1f607', 16))`

Answer (score 4):

here's a complete solution:

```
>>> ''.join(['{0:x}'.format(ord(x)) for x in unichr(int('FD9B', 16)).encode('utf-8')]).upper()
'EFB69B'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data_from_file='\uFD9B'
unicode(data_from_file,"unicode_escape").encode("utf8")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u'\uFD9B'.encode('utf-8')
'\xef\xb6\x9b'
>>> s = 'FD9B'
>>> i = int(s, 16)
>>> i
64923
>>> unichr(i)
u'\ufd9b'
>>> _.encode('utf-8')
'\xef\xb6\x9b'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the input string length is a multiple of 4 (i.e. your unicode code points are UCS-2 encoded), then try this:

```
import struct

def unihex2utf8hex(arg):
    count= len(arg)//4
    uniarr= struct.unpack('!%dH' % count, arg.decode('hex'))
    return u''.join(map(unichr, uniarr)).encode('utf-8').encode('hex')

>>> unihex2utf8hex('fd9b')
'efb69b'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you might encounter an error while using `unichr` with wide unicode characters:

```
>>> n = int('0001f600', 16)
>>> unichr(n)
ValueError: unichr() arg not in range(0x10000) (narrow Python build)
```

Here is another approach for wide unicode on narrow python builds:

```
>>> n = int('0001f600', 16)
>>> s = '\\U{:0>8X}'.format(n)
>>> s = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> s.encode("utf-8")
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x80'
```

And using the original question's value:

```
>>> n = int('FD9B', 16)
>>> s = '\\u{:0>4X}'.format(n)
>>> s = s.decode('unicode-escape')
>>> s.encode("utf-8")
'\xef\xb6\x9b'
```