# How can I replace '%' to '\x' in Python

Tags: python, string, character-encoding, base64

My aim is that converting base64 encoding "%EB" string to "\xEB". However, as soon as I tried, I found that it is hard and can't achieved by string.replace nor re.sub both.

My code failed as below:

```
target = '%EB%AF%B8%EB%9F%AC%EC%8A%A4%20%EC%97%A3%EC%A7%80'

target.replace('%','\x')
-> ValueError: invalid \x escape

re.sub('%','\x',target)
-> ValueError: invalid \x escape
```

UPDATED:

Thanks for comments, I tried '\x' and r'\x', however, it seems that those couldn't be a solution.

for example,

```
target = '%EB%AF%B8%EB%9F%AC%EC%8A%A4%20%EC%97%A3%EC%A7%80'
converted1 = target.replace('%',r'\x')
converted2 = target.replace('%','\\x')
converted1
-> '\\xEB\\xAF\\xB8\\xEB\\x9F\\xAC\\xEC\\x8A\\xA4\\x20\\xEC\\x97\\xA3\\xEC\\xA7\\x80'
converted2
-> '\\xEB\\xAF\\xB8\\xEB\\x9F\\xAC\\xEC\\x8A\\xA4\\x20\\xEC\\x97\\xA3\\xEC\\xA7\\x80'
```

Results:

```
print converted1
\xEB\xAF\xB8\xEB\x9F\xAC\xEC\x8A\xA4\x20\xEC\x97\xA3\xEC\xA7\x80
print converted2
\xEB\xAF\xB8\xEB\x9F\xAC\xEC\x8A\xA4\x20\xEC\x97\xA3\xEC\xA7\x80
```

What I want to have is:

```
print "\xEB\xAF\xB8\xEB\x9F\xAC\xEC\x8A\xA4\x20\xEC\x97\xA3\xEC\xA7\x80"
미러스 엣지
```

Comment: Escape the slash: `replace('%', '\\x')`, etc

Answer (score 8):

The method `replace` cannot decode URL-safe string. It just replace character `%` to `\x`.
If you want to decode URL-safe string, you should use `urllib.unquote`.

```
import urllib
target = '%EB%AF%B8%EB%9F%AC%EC%8A%A4%20%EC%97%A3%EC%A7%80'
print urllib.unquote(target)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> target = '%EB%AF%B8%EB%9F%AC%EC%8A%A4%20%EC%97%A3%EC%A7%80'
>>> target.replace('%',r'\x')
'xEBxAFxB8xEBx9FxACxECx8AxA4x20xECx97xA3xECxA7x80'
```

[Why is '\x' invalid in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704654/why-is-x-invalid-in-python)

For the second part of your code, use:

```
print target.replace('%',r'\x').decode('string-escape')
```

Though this fixes your error, the best solution is the one by @kamae

Comment: or one can use `'\\x'` string literal instead of `r'\x'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed difference between CLI of interactive Python and the python source code. What you actually do in your code is changing character "%" in the string into "\x" characters.

What you do from the Python's command line is to enter string with escape code interpreted at the moment of string creation (when you pressed *Enter*). Your string then is unicode and contains binary representation of your Korean characters.

[Converting unicode codepoints to UTF8 hex in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/867866/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf8-hex-in-python) may help you.